# Formatting ISO time using fmtlib

Tags: c++, fmt

I'm trying to get a `std::string` of ISO time using fmtlib.
Consider the following code:

```cpp
const auto t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
const auto creation_time = fmt::format("{:%FT%T%z}", fmt::localtime(t));
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ../deps/fmt-src/include/fmt/chrono.h: In function 'size_t fmt::v7::detail::strftime(char*, size_t, const char*, const tm*)':
> ../deps/fmt-src/include/fmt/chrono.h:377:48: error: format not a string literal, format string not checked [-Werror=format-nonliteral]
> return std::strftime(str, count, format, time);

Which I don't get, as clearly `fmt::localtime(t)` is not a compile-time string.

What am I missing?

Using fmtlib v7.1.3, compiled using the following flags to work on embedded system:

```
target_compile_definitions(fmt PRIVATE FMT_STATIC_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR FMT_USE_DOUBLE=0 FMT_USE_LONG_DOUBLE=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are compiling with the `-Werror=format-nonliteral` compiler flag while the chrono formatter calls `strftime` with a dynamic format string. The solution is to remove `-Werror=format-nonliteral` or add `-Wno-error=format-nonliteral`.

Alternatively you can use {fmt} [5a37e1](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/commit/5a37e182deee09a873777ff3f8e901d117e5f39b) or later where this warning is suppressed.